# animate particle system scale changes

Tags: particles, transforms

I have a particle system on an object, how can I animate the scale of the particles so they change size as the animation progresses?

I ask this actually because I seem to have found out how to do this by accident and I can't fix it. Either its a bug or I've configured something wrong, the particles are trees on a landscape and as my animation progresses, the trees spontaneously change size. I did noticed that when the size changes, sometimes i even see motion blur which makes me think its more likely a setting I set while trying to create randomness not knowing it would have this effect?

Comment: if my answer doesn't help, please provide blend file because you didn't show us any settings you made, thx.

Comment: I appreciate the help! the blend file is huge so posting it probably wouldn't work. My problem is I don't know which setting I changed that was causing this to happen. Although I did notice yesterday that a setting called Hair Dynamics was enabled, I don't remember enabling that, but I tried disabling it. its rendering now so I can report back later if that or your suggestion ended up fixing it. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the scale via texture and this slider (size) here:

[image]